# Handling Callback URLs in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

My REST Service takes in a JMeter HTTP request and one of the parameters in the request is a callback url.

The REST Service uses this callback url to post back a response.

Is there any JMeter Listener I can use to receive the callback i.e. so that the REST Service can send the response back to a JMeter Listener.

And if possible the Listener can then send in another HTTP Request based on the response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question. But I think you want to receive your REST response and make another request to URL in the response...

By that way, you need to "catch" the response by using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), store URL in the response to a JMeter Variable. Then, you create HTTP Request, and put URL in that JMeter Variable into request.